# Allow squid proxy connexion with port

Tags: squid

I have configured a squid proxy with multiple domains allowed and I would like to allow a new one which is `https://sub.domain.com:25443`

My config is

```
acl TEST_DOMAIN dstdomain .domain.com
acl TEST_PORT port 25443
http_access allow TEST_DOMAIN
http_access allow TEST_PORT
```

So it should work with `curl -x https://proxy.com https://sub.domain.com:25443` the reply is `curl: (56) CONNECT tunnel failed, response 403`

I made some test `curl -x https://proxy.com https://sub.domain.com` and it works `curl -x https://proxy.com http://sub.domain.com:25443` also works

But `https` with port `25443` not working

I also tried to add in config

```
acl HTTPS port 443
http_access allow HTTPS
```

But I have the same issue